# Android buttons on GridLayout are not equally spaced

Tags: android

I am learning android and as a part of the process coding a small game. Below is the image of my activity screen:

[image]

As you can see there is a GridLayout containing buttons on different rows and columns. I have given the left and right padding for the GridLayout content to be 15dp. It looks perfect here, however when I start the emulator and the app is loaded, it looks something like this:

[image]

The entire grid is messed up. It is nowhere in the middle and towards the bottom of the screen as it should be.

Here is a small sample of code:

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <!--First row buttons-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_row="1" />
        
        <!--- second row buttons then third and so on--->
        <!--- rest of the buttons with different column and row numbers-->
        <!---- every button has width and height of 80dp----->
</GridLayout>
```

Also when I click the individual button element, it seems that the button does not fill up the entire cell it is in. I tried giving it gravity, weight but nothing changed.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: use GridView instead

Comment: I would suggest not using a set width wand height for the buttons and instead using the stretchColumns attribute of GridView

Comment: For something like this you would be better off using a recycler view with a grid adapter, have a look at recyclerviews and how they work, this way you will be better equipped for future projects

Comment: remove alignparentleft and alignparentstart

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your GridLayout:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

By the way, I would not suggest to use GridLayout, it is less flexible and less customizable than the alternative solutions. For example you can use RelativeLayout or a single RecicleView and fill the elements programatically.

Answer (score 0):

OK

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

for `RelativeLayout`  so at your case the correct code will be like this

You will set the width to `wrap_content` and the `layout_gravity`
and choose what't gravity you want i see in your code you want it to be centered in the screen so use `center` value

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gameGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <!--First row buttons-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_row="1" />

<!-- The other raws -->
    </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set width and height match_parent and set padding left and right for Grid layout and also set `gravity = "center_horizontal|center_vertical`" . Hope this will help.

Comment: I dont want to match parent as there are going to be other widgets on that activity as well. Ex: There is a text view widget above the grid layout.